# Cannot access power plans via WMI

Tags: wmi, admin

I am trying to enumerate Windows power plans through very straightforward code that has been working for several years. On my Windows 10 64-bit machine, however, I am getting errors when I try to enumerate a collection of power plans.

I realize Visual Foxpro code is like a fossil, but it is still pretty easy to read:

```
loSchemes = CREATEOBJECT("Collection")  
loWMIService = GETOBJECT("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2\power")
loItems = loWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PowerPlan")
FOR EACH loItem IN loItems
    loSchemes.Add(loItem)
ENDFOR
```

The code has been working for years, from Windows XP up through (I think, anyway), Windows 10.

The error happens after `loItems` is instantiated via the `ExecQuery()` method call. The object exists and has visible properties, but if I try to access anything in the debugger, it says the expression cannot be evaluated. If I wrap the iterating FOR loop in a TRY..CATCH, the error I get is:

> OLE error code 0x80070668: Only administrators have permission to add,
>   remove, or configure server software during a Terminal services remote
>   session. If you want to install or configure software on the server,
>   contact your network administrator.

So, it looks like I am being locked out from power plan information because the process thinks I am remotely trying to change the configuration even though I am accessing WMI data from the local machine (where I do have administrator rights, incidentally).

I downloaded a "WMI Explorer" tool from Code Plex, and I actually get the same problem there when I try to iterate over `Win32_PowerPlan`. The log returns an error:

> Failed to enumerate instances from Win32_PowerPlan. ERROR:

(That is the literal response -- no actual error is listed.)

This makes me think this isn't just some sort of Foxpro issue.

### Edit

I downloaded a WMI process explorer from Sapien, and it displays a UAC prompt every time it starts, running it with elevated privileges. Both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of that software can query `Win32_PowerPlan` and display results. I then ran the Code Plex WMI Explorer as administrator and it was also able to iterate over `Win32_PowerPlan` without errors. So, the issue appears to be unrelated to "bit"-ness and has everything to do with WMI data access requiring administrator privileges even though I am running locally using a login that does, in fact, have administrator privileges. Needless to say, I am still stumped... For the record, *I can still access all sorts of other information via WMI: processor info, memory usage, processes, services, IP Address, and OS description.* All of those modules still work perfectly. But when it comes to the `\root\cimv2\power` namespace and accessing power plans, no joy.

### Further edit

Some other questions mention `ImpersonationLevel`, saying I might need to explicitly set the level to "impersonate" (an enumeration constant = 3). I am playing with my WMIService object and can read and write the impersonation level, but it is 3 by default. I raised it to 4 ("delegate") and still cannot access the power plan items. The query runs fine, but an error gets thrown when I try to access any properties of `loItems`. If I reduce the impersonation level to 1 ("anonymous"), then an "Access denied" error gets thrown on the `ExecQuery()` call. Finally, level 2 ("identify") allows the query and I can access the `Count` property without an error being thrown. But zero items are returned where there should be 5. I am confused now more than ever.

In summary, I cannot access power plan information from my local machine, even though I have administrator privileges, regardless. This is on a Windows 10 Professional 64-bit installation (all updates up-to-date), definitely no Terminal Server software installed.

Comment: I've got the same issue trying to query `SELECT * FROM Win32_PowerPlan` from C#.

Comment: Do you mean you get "Access denied" when running the query itself, or that you get back a collection of items that cannot be accessed? Thanks for checking the situation in .NET!

Comment: OK, tried some C# code, I can create a collection of objects for Win32_PowerPlan, but if I try to enumerate over the collection or simply ask for a count, an exception is thrown. It is a COM exception but I cannot get any information from it -- Message property is empty. But I assume it is the same error.

Comment: Exactly, that's my experience. Could it be recent changes in Windows 10?

Comment: Could be, but I am completely unsure of when this stopped working. I am not even sure I have ever tested it on 64-bit Windows 10. I do think it used to work on my 32-bit Windows 10 machine, but this is rather old code.